# Sql Server 2012 .. AD account has access to execute SP, but i don't know why

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've written a very simple web service that uses a specified application pool, which uses a particular AD account. I've created a very simple stored procedure which writes one row to a table, one of the fields defaulting to SYSTEM_USER. I have checked this field in the table, and it is populated with aforementioned AD account. However, I have checked the database, and there is no mention of the AD account anywhere in database security or server security. I've checked groups, etc but still seem unable to find any trace of the AD account. It has to be there somewhere, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Is there a way of identifying "how", security-wise, this stored procedure was executed? I've tried using tracer but cannot see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`xp_logininfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190369.aspx) function should show how the account has access to the server/database. Run:

```
EXEC xp_logininfo '<AD account name>'
```

This should return the highest group membership which gives the account access to the server, in the `permission_path` column.

Comment: You rock. Thank you.